# Reading COBOL datastructures from Java

Tags: java, data-structures, cobol, copybook

Is there a way to read COBOL data in a Java program? More concretely I'm confronted with the following case:

I have a file with fixed length records of data. The data definition is done as COBOL copybooks. I think of a library which is taking into account the copybooks and would be able to read those records.

Ideally, it should be possible to generate basic Java classes and structures based on the copybook information. In a later step the datarecords would be parsed and the data filled into objects of those generated classes.

Are there any other techniques to cope with the problem of reading COBOL data?

Comment: Which Cobolplatform are you using?

Comment: Why are you asking? The cobol platform doesn't change the problem, or does it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could look at [JRecord](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) or [cb2java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2java/). Both allow you to access COBOL files, but neither will generate the full classes.

---

Update Jan 2011

Since the original answer:

- JRecord continues be developed. There is now a `JRecord Code generator` available as either a standalone program or in the [Recordeditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/).
  This `Code Generator` will build `JRecord JRecord` code from a COBOL Copybook. See [RecordEditor Jrecord CodeGen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-for-a-cobol-copybook))
- Development on **cb2java** has stopped
- [cobol2j](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cobol2j) has been written. There have been no updates for a year.
- There is also [Legstar](http://www.legsem.com/legstar/) again nothing published for a few years

#### Update Aug 2017

The [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) has a Generate option for generating **Java / JRecord** code from a COBOL Copybook. See [RecordEditor Code Generation notes](http://record-editor.sourceforge.net/RecordEditorGenerate.htm) for details.

#### Update Jan 2018

There is some information on generating *Java~JRecord* code in this question / answer:

*[How do you generate java~jrecord code for a Cobol copybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-fror-a-cobol-copybook)*

Comment: The fourth link is to a local file (drive F: on a Windows system).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I have done that before. I used an ODBC connection to COBOL files, and then with jdbc:odbc bridge, I used metadata information to generate classes, read data and port it all to Oracle.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/Metadata-DB-Info.htm) is a nice tutorial on how to access metada information with JDBC. [Here](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Database-Metadata-with-JDBC/13753) is another one.

Keep in mind that you don't need the JDBC:ODBC bridge approach. If you can get a native JDBC driver to connect to your Cobol DataSource, it will be better. In this regard, I also used an IBM native driver. Don't remember the name though. It was a long time ago.

Comment: Your way to access cobol datastructures sounds interesting. Can you provide more information on how you did it? I didn't know that odbc supports accessing cobol datastructures.

Comment: Sure. What would you like? A tutorial on how to access Metadata information with JDBC?

Comment: It is not about accessing the metadata, that part I do understand. However, the question is more how to use a odbc connection to access data stored in a cobol data-record file. Such a file doesn't per se contain information about the structures used.

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be some [commercial solutions](https://ssl.kundenserver.de/shop.softproject.de/en/products/COBOL-Copybook-Toolkit/) for this. Alternatively you can use [cb2xml](http://cb2xml.sourceforge.net/) to convert the copybooks to XML, and then import the XML into Java using whatever mechanism you require.

Comment: Thanks, however, the cb2xml only reads data definition and transforms it into xml. What I need is also a tool to read the actual data and transform it into java structures.

Comment: You could use Apache's XMLBEANS to create java data structures from XML.

Comment: Or JAXB. Or handle-roll your own mechanism (a little more hard work admittedly) The cb2xml only gets you halfway, but it does take the COBOL and transforms it into something from which you can implement various different solutions...

Answer (score 2):

I have used Bruce's JRecord (from sourceforge) package for my project. It took only couple of days to learn to use it and saved me months of work in rolling out a much less general solution on my own. I recommend it highly.

Answer (score 1):

[Microfocus](http://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/nx40/dicofj.htm) provide a way of calling OO COBOL from Java.

"You can write classes in OO COBOL which can be called from Java programs as though they were Java classes. You do this by providing a Java wrapper class, which provides a function for each method in the OO COBOL class. The Net Express Class and Method Wizards make this easy for you, by generating the Java code at the same time as the COBOL code."

They also provide a tool called Enterprise Server which allows COBOL to interact with web services.

If you have a COBOL program A, the tool allows you to expose A's interface section as a web service.

Of course, because A now has a web service any other type of program (command line, Windows application, Java, ASP etc.) can now also call it and hence pass the COBOL data across to a Java program.

Answer (score 1):

BEA used to have a product named JAM that was used to communicate with mainframe COBOL programs.  It included a tool that would read copybooks and generate both corresponding Java POD classes and data conversion code.

I don't know if this is still available, I lost track of it when I left BEA.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Javolution Struct](http://javolution.org/apidocs/javolution/io/Struct.html).

You can then use a macro to convert your COBOL datat into `Struct`.

Answer (score 1):

Rational Application Developer can read COBOL source code and generate Java classes. The generated classes have methods for accessing the various part of the COBOL data structure. The class that is generated is compatible with the [J2EE Connector Architecture](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/connector/). To create a class in your project, select File, New, Other then select the CICS/IMS Java Data Binding wizard under J2C. Click next. Choose COBOL to Java for mapping. Select your COBOL file. Select the structure you wish to generate a Java class for then click Finish and there you go. There are of course a number of options you can select along the way that I didn't mention. For more information search Help for J2C.

Comment: They had this feature on a special version of RAD called "RAD for z". Have they moved the functionality to base RAD now?