# nested cobol data to one fixed-length string

Tags: cobol

I have to call a stored procedure that takes a nested cobol datastructure in form of a plain string of 400 bytes length.

I want to avoid to assemble this string manually.

Are there (online) tools that do such a conversion? (i.e. enter structured cobol data and compute the in-memory representation)

If not, what would be the best / easiest way to get the string manually?

Comment: Tool-recommendation is not on-topic here. Neither is opinion on best/easiest (or other types of request for opinion). If you have the data, it is already in a 400-byte lump. I'm not sure what you mean by a nested COBOL datastructure. If you can tidy some of these things up, it'll help to keep your question from going On Hold.

Comment: As Bill said, It is difficult to understand what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the tool I was looking for:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.j2c.doc/topics/tcreatingdatabinding.html

found via old SO question: 
[Reading cobol datastructures from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802122/reading-cobol-datastructures-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

As Bill said, It is difficult to understand what you want, so can you clarify the question. The

If you do not have the **COBOL copybook** you need to get it.

But If you want to know the starting position for COBOL fields (in a COBOL Copybook):

1. Most COBOL compilers will tell you how they will allocate the fields (you may have to specify a compiler option). [GNU-Cobol](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/) has compatibility modes for several other Compilers (Microfocus, IBM etc) and could be used to get a map for those compilers.
2. For the mainframe, File-Aid will give you a field map.
3. For mainframe COBOL, the [cb2xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/)-project will convert a COBOL-Copybook to an Xml file (which lists field starting positions and lengths.
4. The [Record-Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) has a cobol analysis option (*Utilities >>> COBOL Copybook Analysis*) that will give you a Field map (Mainframe, Gnu-Cobol, Fujitsu-pc) COBOL compilers). The record-editor will also let you enter fields fields and create a file

---

if you are using Java, [LegStar](http://www.legsem.com/legstar/) or JRecord could be worth looking at